# ampersand C reference like operator in java. meaning?

Tags: java, syntax, ampersand

I encountered this piece of code

```
do {
    if (higherQuality &amp;&amp; w &gt; targetWidth) {
        w /= 2;
        if (w &lt; targetWidth) {
            w = targetWidth;
        }
    }

    if (higherQuality &amp;&amp; h &gt; targetHeight) {
        h /= 2;
        if (h &lt; targetHeight) {
            h = targetHeight;
        }
    } 
    BufferedImage tmp = new BufferedImage(w, h, type);
    Graphics2D g2 = tmp.createGraphics();
    g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_INTERPOLATION, hint);
    g2.drawImage(ret, 0, 0, w, h, null);
    g2.dispose();

    ret = tmp;
} while (w != targetWidth || h != targetHeight);
```

I don't get the meaning of these if conditions

```
if (higherQuality &amp;&amp; w &gt; targetWidth)
```

and

```
if (higherQuality &amp;&amp; h &gt; targetHeight)
```

It resembles C's *&variable* reference operator to me. I am new to java but I know it doesn't support such thing and I was unable to google out any other meaning of ampersand in java aside from standard bitwise and logical AND.
I would appreciate any explanation.
Thank you.

Comment: Are those HTML entities intentional?

Comment: I don't see how it resembles a C reference variable (?) Why wouldn't this just be a compound boolean expression? Or are you just misinterpreting HTML escaping as being Java? In which case, simply trying to compile this would put a lie to that idea.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`&amp;` and `&gt;` are [HTML character references](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Html_entity#HTML_character_references); it looks like the above code has simply been badly encoded on whatever website you found it on.

So for reference, this:

```
if (higherQuality &amp;&amp; w &gt; targetWidth)
```

should have been displayed as this:

```
if (higherQuality && w > targetWidth)
```

Comment: Huh! thought something like that could be the case

Comment: EDIT - I've looked at the html sourcecode and yeah, there is some mess. It should be `higherQuality && w > targetWidth` in the first condition. Didn't know these character references.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

After decoding HTLM the code reads

```
if (higherQuality && h > targetHeight)
```

and then the `&&` is Java's [Conditional-AND](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/opsummary.html) operator.

Answer (score 0):

Someone just double-HTML-encoded it by accident. They're actually just regular operators, and the code should look like this:

```
do {
    if (higherQuality && w > targetWidth) {
        w /= 2;
        if (w < targetWidth) {
            w = targetWidth;
        }
    }

    if (higherQuality && h > targetHeight) {
        h /= 2;
        if (h < targetHeight) {
            h = targetHeight;
        }
    }
    BufferedImage tmp = new BufferedImage(w, h, type);
    Graphics2D g2 = tmp.createGraphics();
    g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_INTERPOLATION, hint);
    g2.drawImage(ret, 0, 0, w, h, null);
    g2.dispose();

    ret = tmp;
} while (w != targetWidth || h != targetHeight);
```